# When should I add "~~" before the end of StringCases

Tags: string-manipulation

I see these two lines of codes in my book, in which I find sometimes the

> ~~

was added to the end of the StringCases and sometimes not.

For example:

```
StringCases["+string +patterns are +quite +easy", "+" ~~_]
```

In this case,`"+"~~_` doesn't contain `~~` at the end.

```
StringCases["the [important] word", "[" ~~ x__ ~~ "]" -> Framed[x]]
```

In this case, `~~ x__ ~~`  contains `~~` at the end.
I am very confused about these situations.

Thanks.

Comment: `~~` is an infix operator and it is never at the end of a string pattern. In your examples, it is never at the end.

Comment: @Szabolcs  Thanks, and I have changed my question.

Comment: It is not `~~ x__ ~~`, but `"[" ~~ x__ ~~ "]"`. `~~` is an infix operator that concatenates parts of string patterns. The last part of this pattern is the `"]"` character.

Comment: When should I add ``~~`` before the last part of StringCases?

Comment: If you read `~~` as **followed by**, some of the confusion would be addressed.

Comment: @Syed Okay, I know now. Thank you much.

Comment: If you say you know now then isolate the two bracketed words as an exercise to improve understanding: `"some [important] words in [all] discourse"`

Comment: @Syed ``some [important] words in [all] discourse", "[" ~~ Shortest[x__] ~~ "]" -> Framed[x]]`` . Is it right?